# How to extract some text from a string in java

Tags: java

I have string:

> Adding offert to database.
>  number of
>   agreement: 98393553553 
>  number of accounting:
>   1242422222222222224242
>  Agreement in step:
>   Accounting

How to extract text: 98393553553 (text has always the same number of characters - 11 characters) using Java. Text before: 98393553553 it can be different (sometimes).

Comment: Your question doesn't show any effort of neither you trying to solve your problem on your own; nor you checking stack overflow for this question. Do you really assume that you are the very first person who is asking here how to parse strings in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `String.split()` with the delimiter `:`, and `String.substring()` on index 1 of the `String[]` obtained from the earlier `String.split()`.

Comment: Good effort but in theory that will still return `98393553553
 number of accounting` ;)

Comment: That's why I said use `String.substring()` as he said the number is of length 11.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regular expression matcher for this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

  String line = .........; //your input line
  String pattern = "number of agreement:\\s*(\\d+)";

  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Number of agreement: " + m.group(0) );
  } else {
     System.out.println("Number of agreement not found");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.split()` and store it into a `String Array`. Then finally extract whatever you want from the array.